# javascript click method not working for touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
onclick: function() {
  element.click();
}
```

it is giving me error.

> Performing operations that require explicit user interaction on
>   touch start events is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around
>   January 2017. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5649871251963904 for more
>   details.

**so click method doesn't working for touch events**. Any alternative? Should I change touch events to mouse events?

Tested on mobile devices.

thanks

Since element is `input type file` so click method will open the file browser. Is there any alternative so, I don't need to use click method and file browser will open.

Comment: try after including jquery tocuhpunch js. http://touchpunch.furf.com/   cdn lick is here --->   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Comment: @Sharmila i can't add library in my project . because that is not in my hand :(

Comment: oh so sad then :(

Comment: @Sharmila it is so small library . i can add into my function . but i cannot understand what they are doing . seems like they are converting touch events to mouse events

Comment: it is no `so small`. inspect `depends` section, it requires some `jquery.ui` components. Also, it looks like abandoned: [github issues](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues?q=is%3Aopen+sort%3Acreated-desc), last commit is 2 years old.

Comment: Heres a good resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events

Comment: Im not sure mahi. Once i had this issue while developing hybrid mob app. Resolved when this added.